# Laravel Validate Field X if Field Y == "something"

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form in Laravel for which I need help with the validation of the fields.
The form has 3 text fields and 1 drop-down button.
Now 2 out of the 3 text fields are required only when the drop-down is set to a certain value.

Here are my 3 text fields and the drop-down button code:

```
<textarea class="form-control w-100 flex-fill instructions" id="instructions-1" name="instructions[]" rows="4" placeholder="Instructions"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-md bg-white dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="button[]" id="button-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Model</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="button-1"><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-item-model-1" href="#">Model</a><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-item-engenius-1" href="#">Engenius</a>
<input type="text" class="text-body px-2 py-1 text" name="model[]" id="model-1" value="" placeholder="Enter Model" />
<input type="text" class="text-body px-2 py-1 text" name="pincode[]" id="pincode-1" value="" placeholder="Enter Pincode" />
```

Here is my validation code:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
        'button.*' => 'required',
        'instructions.*' => 'required|min:5',
        'model.*' => 'required_if:button.*,Model|min:5',
        'pincode.*' => 'required_if:button.*,Model|min:5',
    ]);
```

I need to validate the model and pincode text fields only if the drop-down button has a value Model.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.
I was trying to use the input type button's value for validation but the form post would not send the value of the button.
So instead I added a hidden text field that would save the value of drop down.
In that way, I was able to check if my Drop down was Model only then the text fields model and pincode are required.

Below is my update HTML code:
<

```
textarea class="form-control w-100 flex-fill instructions" id="instructions-1" name="instructions[]" rows="4" placeholder="Instructions"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-md bg-white dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="button[]" id="button-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Model</button>
<input type="hidden" name="job_type[]" id="job_type-1" value="Model" />
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="button-1"><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-item-model-1" href="#">Model</a><a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown-item-engenius-1" href="#">Engenius</a>
<input type="text" class="text-body px-2 py-1 text" name="model[]" id="model-1" value="" placeholder="Enter Model" />
<input type="text" class="text-body px-2 py-1 text" name="pincode[]" id="pincode-1" value="" placeholder="Enter Pincode" />
```

Here is my updated validation code:

```
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'job_type.*' => 'required',
        'instructions.*' => 'required|min:5',
        'model.*' => 'required_if:job_type.*,Model',
        'pincode.*' => 'required_if:job_type.*,Model',
    ]);
```